# Oracle SQL *plus EXCEPT ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i wrote this query, but it gives me an error:

```
select c.sid
from catalog c
where exists ((select p.color from parts p)
except (select p2.color from parts p2 where p2.color != 'Red'));
```

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

can you tell me where is incorrect?

catalog:

```
   SID        PID       COST
```

---

```
     1          3         .5
     1          4         .5
     1          8       11.7
     2          3        .55
     2          8       7.95
     2          1       16.5
     3          8       12.5
     3          9          1
     4          5        2.2
     4          6 1247548.23
     4          7 1247548.23
```

parts:

```
   PID PNAME                               COLOR
```

---

```
     1 Left Handed Bacon Stretcher Cover   Red
     2 Smoke Shifter End                   Black
     3 Acme Widget Washer                  Red
     4 Acme Widget Washer                  Silver
     5 I Brake for Crop Circles Sticker    Translucent
     6 Anti-Gravity Turbine Generator      Cyan
     7 Anti-Gravity Turbine Generator      Magenta
     8 Fire Hydrant Cap                    Red
     9 7 Segment Display                   Green
```

Comment: For starters, your EXISTS clause doesn't connect to the catalog table C at all. Also, EXCEPT is called MINUS in oracle. Can you please post your data structures and some sample data, and what you want this query to accomplish? You can just edit your answer to add this information.

Comment: @NWest i added the information
and i want to know sid of suppliers who supply only red parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to know sid of suppliers who supply only red parts

You can write:

```
SELECT c.sid
  FROM catalog c
  JOIN parts p
    ON p.pid = c.pid
 WHERE p.color = 'Red'
MINUS
SELECT c.sid
  FROM catalog c
  JOIN parts p
    ON p.pid = c.pid
 WHERE p.color <> 'Red'
;
```

The part before the `MINUS` finds all the suppliers who supply red parts; the part after the `MINUS` finds all the suppliers who supply *non*-red parts; so, the whole query finds all distinct suppliers who supply *only* red parts.

Comment: i didn't know '<>' before, and that makes it much easier
thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisPark: You're welcome! And to clarify, `!=` and `<>` are equivalent in Oracle. I prefer to use `<>` because it's standard SQL, but you can use whichever you prefer.